# Invalid URI with UNC path

Tags: c#, uri, unc

I have a path that uses some unc paths in the background such as:

\\crfile2\..some folders..\myFile.lbp

and needs to check if the file exists (won't exist in many cases).  I have a simple check that reads the file if it exists.  It works fine on almost all cases, but I have one customer that is getting an error:

```
Unhandled Error: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at RDES.Common.RDLicenseCommon.LicenseBypassData.<GetBypassData>b__0(String x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

This seems like a valid UNC path correct?  I'm not sure where the error is here, and even more so I find it confusing that my machine and hundreds of others use the same path string with no issues but this one user is getting this issue.  I know it's very limited because for him it's cause a crash on startup and the program is used by enough people that when I post something with a critical issue like that I know it from many people in very short order (not that I ever have posted anything like that...).  Anyway any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code line where the exception is being thrown:

```
string myPath = AllValidPaths.Where(x => VerifyFileExists(new Uri(x),500)).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can see by the stack that the exception is being thrown by the constructor of the URI inside of the lambda expression.

Comment: Do you happen to have some code snippets?

Comment: It is probably a credential issue.  To get access either you need to be an admin or the drive needs to be shared.  The group policy in the network also can effect the results.  Are the two PCs (local PC and File Server) in the same Group?

Comment: I'm not sure code snippets would matter, it's throwing the error creating the URI from the path given (of course filled in with actual folders)...

Comment: Well in most cases the server probably doesn't exist...  The system is just an override for a couple large customers that have worked out special licensing, for most customers the files don't exist and it should just skip the system.  The error is not on the customers where it exists, it's on one that it doesn't exist (unless they have the same name file server I guess...)

Comment: Verified with the customer that they do not have that server or machine name on their network, so it should just not exist at all.  However it's throwing the exception constructing the URI, should it need permissions tot he machine just to construct the URI?

Comment: You have verified X is correctly populated in the linq statement?  Is AllValidPaths being populated from something in which an invalid x value is present?  Since the server does not exist that would certainly cause the error message.

Comment: AllVallidPaths is currently populated with a predetermined set of values (3 strings currently) so it's pretty well hard coded but maybe I will put some type of feedback inside the lambda and see if it's getting something strange in there somehow...

Comment: Why would the server not existing cause an error on the constructor?  And why would it work on most machines but not in this one environment?  I don't have the server on my test network and it doesn't throw any errors...